# Unable to view Careers page

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I am currently unable to view my own Careers 2.0 page at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/austynmahoney. It just redirects to an [error page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/austynmahoney).

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: I am having the issue as well on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv

Comment: I am also unable to edit/view my profile once logged in. The link Jeroen posted also redirects me to an error page.

Comment: @AustynMahoney I see the error in our logs, I'll be digging into this in just a little bit.

Comment: @rossipedia: it works again here.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be happening on only one or two of our web servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a build issue, should be resolved.